# How can I diagnose php cli command execution time inside a docker container

Tags: docker, php, bash

I've recently migrated an event subscription service called by a bash script from Ubuntu, into a Dockerised container.

The Docker image I am using is: `FROM php:7.1-apache`

The script itself is pretty straightforward:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$(dirname $0)"
OUTPUT=""

while true
do
    OUTPUT=""
    OUTPUT=$OUTPUT$(php $DIR/../bin/cli.php bash:v1:issueEvents)
    OUTPUT=$OUTPUT$(php $DIR/../bin/cli.php bash:v1:processCustomerAccountEventSubscriptions)
    OUTPUT=$OUTPUT$(php $DIR/../bin/cli.php bash:v1:processProductionOrderEventSubscriptions)
    OUTPUT=$OUTPUT$(php $DIR/../bin/cli.php bash:v1:processWebEnquiryEventSubscriptions)
    OUTPUT=$OUTPUT$(php $DIR/../bin/cli.php bash:v1:processWebOrderEventSubscriptions)
    OUTPUT=$OUTPUT$(php $DIR/../bin/cli.php bash:v1:processWebQuoteEventSubscriptions)

    if [ -z "$OUTPUT" ]; then
        sleep 10
    fi
done
```

A complete round trip from event subscription to processing would take about 30 seconds on the host OS. Inside a container it is taking around 10 minutes.

My initial suspicion was that DNS was slowing things down, but I've installed `dnsutils` and the lookup times are the same both inside and outside the container.

I'd like advice regarding how I'd go about investigating the cause of this slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

The general process of debugging inside the container is the same as debugging outside of one.  The only thing that you generally need to know is that you can use `docker exec` to attach a bash shell inside a running container, or override the command with `--entrypoint` to launch bash instead, and then run the script manually.

At that point, your question becomes "How do I debug slow execution times in a PHP script?".  That is not really in scope for this site, but you can start with a few basic things: add print statements or attach a profiler to see where things are getting slow, and then narrow it down from there.